# ViewDidLoad Called two times

Tags: ios, viewdidload, uiwindow

I my app once user successfully logged In. I will call HOME notification, after that in HomeViewController ViewDidLoad called two times. Can anyone help on this?

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {      
        //-- Notification Observer
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(HomeNotification:)name:@"HOME"object:nil];

        return YES;
    }

    #pragma mark - Sidemenu & Home
    - (void)HomeNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
    {
        UIStoryboard *sideMenuSB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:SB_SideMenu bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        SideMenuViewCntrl *sideMenuVC = [sideMenuSB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:VC_SideMenu];

        UIStoryboard *HomeSB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:SB_Home bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        HomeViewController *homeVC = [HomeSB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:VC_Home];
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [HomeSB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];

        MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = nil;
        if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"HOME"])
        {
            container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController containerWithCenterViewController:homeVC leftMenuViewController:sideMenuVC rightMenuViewController:nil];
        }

 Adding view to window will call viewdidload multiple times?
        [container setLeftMenuViewController:sideMenuVC];
        [container setCenterViewController:navigationController];
        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.window.rootViewController = container;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
```

Comment: You are possibly creating 2 instances of HomeViewController. The second one could be created by the side menu or the navigation. Additionally, what do you get when you put a breakpoint in the viewDidLoad of HomeScreenViewController and "po self" in the console? Do you get the same description twice?

Comment: Yes. I am getting this twice. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have added Home and side menu view controller two times in SideMenu container.

```
container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController containerWithCenterViewController:homeVC leftMenuViewController:sideMenuVC rightMenuViewController:nil];
```

Once I deleted the below code,it works fine now....

```
[container setLeftMenuViewController:sideMenuVC];
[container setCenterViewController:navigationController];
```